# IIS7 running a site under a limited user account

Tags: iis-7, permissions

Can I run a site on my server under a user account that can't access any other sites or folders apart from its own and its children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes certainly, you need to adjust the identity of the applicaiton pool that your site runs in.

Your best option would be to create an account that has the permissions you need, then create a new application pool based on an exisiting workin one. Then alter the identity of the pool to use the restricted account you created. The steps for doing this are as follows:

- Open IIS Manager.
- In the Connections pane, expand the server node and click Application Pools.
- On the Application Pools page, select the application pool for which you want to specify an identity, and then click Advanced Settings in the Actions pane.
- For the Identity property, click the ... button to open the Application Pool Identity dialog box.
- If you want to use a custom identity, select the Custom account option and click Set to open the Set Credentials dialog box. Then type the custom account name in the User name text box, type a password in the Password text box, retype the password in the Confirm password text box, and then click OK.
- Click OK to dismiss the Application Pool Identity dialog box.

> Source:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170%28WS.10%29.aspx